# Best way to find polygons wrapping a given point MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geo

I have an arbitary point the represents the position of a house. In my MongoDB I have a collection with polygons representing different areas (similar to zip codes).

I want to return the areas in the collection, where the given point is within that area.

Currently I am converting the point into a "small" box and uses a query like this **(which works as expected)**:

(Point that was boxified: `[56.121371, 13.114797]`)

```
db.areas.find({
        "area" : {
                "$geoIntersects" : {
                        "$geometry" : {
                                "type" : "Polygon",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        [
                                                [
                                                        56.120371,
                                                        13.113797
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        56.120371,
                                                        13.115797
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        56.122371,
                                                        13.115797
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        56.122371,
                                                        13.113797
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                        56.120371,
                                                        13.113797
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                }
        }
});
```

I have tried to use `$near` but it only works with points. I also tried `$geoWithin` without success; my guess is that it check if the collections documents are within the query, and not if the query is within the documents.

This should be a very common query, so I wonder **if there is better way to do this** rather then creating a "small" polygon? It feels like a "workaround".

Comment: did you try $geoIntersects with type Point?

Comment: That works! Can't believe I didn't try that...

Comment: Just create an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Believe me, I only thought of it because it's the sort of thing I would have overlooked too!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [$geoIntersects](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) operator allows querying for intersection of two geoJSON objects, and it works with all geometries, including `{ type: "Point" }`